# Printing an image on print stylesheet

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

Am attempting to print an image not defined within the html of a page and as part of this solution the html is not accessible to be changed. I want to be able to define a new image as part of the print stylesheet to be printed once user selects print option. Please see header section as an attempt to show image.

Have tried as follows:

```
    @media print {


    /* Header */

#printHeader {
display: block;
background url(../html/link/link/linkname;
}

#header {
display: block;
height:75px;
width:75px;
}

#print-header {
display: block;
}


/* applied for body tag */
body {
    font-family:"Arial", Times, serif;
    overflow: visible;
    font-size: 12px;
}

/* Redefinition of TD in general.css */
td {
    font-family:"Arial", Times, serif;
    font-size:12px;
}

/* Redefinition of value from enquiry.css */
.columnheader {
    font-family:"Arial", Times, serif;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#6A1A41;
}

/*Standard navigation Bars */

.extra-nav {
    display:none;

    }

.extra-nav ul {
   display:none;

   }
.extra-nav li {
display:none;

}

.active-tab {
display:none;
}

li.nonactive-tab{

display:none;

}

#commandsViewport {
display:none;
}

nav-menu {
display:none;
}

#nav-menu li {
display:none;
}

/* Direct Debit Header */

aheader{
font-family:"Arial",Sans-serif;
font-size:24px;
color:#6A1A41;
}

/* External Standing Order Header */

bheader{
font-family:"Arial",Sans-serif;
font-size:24px;
color:#6A1A41;
}

/* Internal Standing Order Header */

cheader{
font-family:"Arial",Sans-serif;
font-size:24px;
color:#6A1A41;
}
/* Footer Bar */

#footernav {

visibility:hidden;
}

.footernav {
visibility:hidden;
}

/* The solely fragment that should be printed */
.printableFragment {
    display: block;
}
/* fragement that will not be printed */
.notPrintableFragment {
    display: block;
}

/* Hides "drill" button */  
.enqdrilldowncell {
    display: none;
}

/* Hids "next" button in the version */
.belowDealButtonBox {
    display: none;
}
 /* Applied for images */
img { 
    display: none;

}
/* used in enquiry selection */ 
.noPrint {
    display: block;
}
    }
```

Comment: you cannot print background images unless you have specifically told your browser to do so, you could try using the :after psuedo class and adding an img tag in there

Comment: Print backgrounds depends on the user print configuration. Which by default is set to not be printed, so as background colors. The isn't a way to force override printer configuration.